# ufw firewall disabled - How to turn it back on?

Tags: networking, command-line, firewall, ufw, find

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and just recently noticed, that my ufw-firewall is turned [off]. I know It's turned [off] by default, but when I set Ubuntu up, I turned [on] the firewall with:

`sudo ufw`, but today I just noticed that ufw was off, so I tried `sudo ufw` again in a terminal window:

```
morgan@morgan-HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo ufw
[sudo] password for morgan: 
ERROR: not enough args
```

I don't know what else to do, to turn ufw back on!! Please help and thanks.  -Morgan Beck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command to enable the firewall is

```
$ sudo ufw enable
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
$ _
```

You can disable the firewall with

```
$ sudo ufw disable
```

You can check the current status of the firewall with

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active
$ _
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. You can close this question by selecting my answer as the correct answer to your question.

Comment: @Morgan: Can you please accept the answer, if your problem is resolved?! [+1] Also check `man ufw` for more detail!

Comment: Im trying to ...but it wont let me